# How to change focus of Azure Kinect? (Azure Kinect Sensor SDK)

Tags: kinect-sdk, azurekinect

The focus of Azure Kinect seems to be very close to the camera (around 20 cm) by default. The image quality looks nice overall, but when zoomed in, it is blurred.

Is there a way to change the focus on start up or while streaming?

I checked several examples, searched the docs, but could find a solution.

I also checked the provided Azure Kinect Viewer, but it does not have a focus option, so I am guessing there is no way to modify it.

References:
[github - AzureKinectSDK](https://microsoft.github.io/Azure-Kinect-Sensor-SDK/master/group___enumerations_gafba23de13b10b11e413485e421aa0468.html#gafba23de13b10b11e413485e421aa0468)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry there is no way to adjust focus.

Comment: This is what I thought too. I hoped I overlooked something.